# Custom IO writes only header, rest of frames seems omitted

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavformat

I'm using libavformat to read packets from rtsp and remux it to mp4 (fragmented).

Video frames are intact, meaning I don't want to transcode/modify/change anything.
Video frames shall be remuxed into mp4 in their original form. (i.e.: NALUs shall remain the same).

I have updated libavformat to latest (currently 4.4).

Here is my snippet:

```
//open input, probesize is set to 32, we don't need to decode anything
avformat_open_input

//open output with custom io
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofctx,...);
ofctx->pb = avio_alloc_context(buffer, bufsize, 1/*write flag*/, 0, 0, &writeOutput, 0);
ofctx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_NOBUFFER | AVFMT_FLAG_FLUSH_PACKETS | AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;

avformat_write_header(...);

//loop
av_read_frame()
LOGPACKET_DETAILS //<- this works, packets are coming
av_write_frame() //<- this doesn't work, my write callback is not called. Also tried with av_write_interleaved_frame, not seem to work.

int writeOutput(void *opaque, uint8_t *buffer, int buffer_size) {
  printf("writeOutput: writing %d bytes: ", buffer_size);
}
```

`avformat_write_header` works, it prints the header correctly.

I'm looking for the reason on why my custom IO is not called after a frame has been read.

There must be some more flags should be set to ask avformat to don't care about decoding, just write out whatever comes in.

More information:
Input stream is a VBR encoded H264. It seems `av_write_frame` calls my write function only in case an SPS, PPS or IDR frame. Non-IDR frames are not passed at all.

### Update

I found out if I request IDR frame at every second (I can ask it from the encoder), `writeOutput` is called at every second.

I created a test: after a client joins, I requested the encoder to create IDRs @1Hz for 10 times. Libav calls `writeOutput` at 1Hz for 10 seconds, but then encoder sets itself back to create IDR only at every 10 seconds. And then libav calls `writeOutput` only at every 10s, which makes my decoder fail. In case 1Hz IDRs, decoder is fine.